# Flutter Sliver AppBar leading color

Tags: flutter, appbar, flutter-sliver, sliverappbar, flutter-sliverappbar

This is a Sliver AppBar.

[image: AppBar]

**How can I change the color of the back arrow ?**

**BUT** I don't want to set `leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.red)` since (I believe) that the Sliver AppBar has the nice property of adapting the lead icon depending on  context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrap the SliverAppBar widget with Theme widget, and change primaryIconTheme color in ThemeData. Here's the code:

```
     Theme(
            data: ThemeData(
                primaryIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.red)),
            child: SliverAppBar(),
          ),
```

Comment: Will test it later and if it works, will let you know  + accept answer. Thanks!